# How add elements to a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have been doing some research on this issue on this forum and others online, but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

My goal with one of the functions in my code is to add 5 karma points to an existing user or create a new user with a karma score of '1' if the user is not there. The user will input a user and id number in a form and then that information will be sent to my php script. That function uses that information to do its magic, but the output is wrong.

What I get is a new user with a karma score of '6'. I left out some of the script which is extraneous to this matter.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<?php

// Array begin 
$karma_score = array(   array("Userid" => 1, "NameID" => 'Doe', "Karma" => 45, "LastLogin" => "2012-08-30"),
                        array("Userid" => 2, "NameID" => 'Smith', "Karma" => 123, "LastLogin" => "2012-09-02"),
                        array("Userid" => 3, "NameID" => 'Chan', "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => "2011-12-23"),
                        array("Userid" => 4, "NameID" => 'Zee', "Karma" => 15, "LastLogin" => "2012-07-01"));

// Counter for amount of users
$counter = count($karma_score);

// Function to print general array
function printArray($a){
    echo '<table border="1px">';
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach(array_keys($a[0]) as $head){
            echo '<th>'.$head.'</th>';
        }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($a as $b) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['Userid'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['NameID'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['Karma'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['LastLogin'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

echo '<br>';

function findInfo()
{
    global $karma_score;
    $counter = count($karma_score);

        foreach ($karma_score as $key => $b) {
            if ($b['NameID'] === $_POST['name'])
                $karma_score[$key]["Karma"] += 5;
            else 
                $karma_score[$counter+1] = array("Userid" => $_POST['id'], "NameID" => $_POST['name'], "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => date("Y-m-d"));     
        }
    echo "<br> Here is your updated table.";
    printArray($karma_score);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    findInfo();
}

?>

<br>


Please enter name and id. If name exists, add 5. If not, add user.
<form action="" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID #">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is my output: The fourth table is what I get when i click submit (the user I entered is 'Alec' and the id I entered is '5'). Thank you in advance!

[image]

EDIT: This is what happens when I submit a user already in the array. The outcome I want is a simple plus 5 karma score for the user.

[image]

Comment: third? fourth? question on this small piece of code are you doing anything yourself?

Comment: @Dagon that's quite immature and unprofessional. This is a small snipet of my code as I mentioned. I apologize for bothering you and causing such stress to your life. We're not all fantastic coders as you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, your looping is always compare `NameID` and if not match, you add element to array, whereas values of element `NameID` in is not always same to your value looking for. in your looping has added 3 times to element array (in value thats not match to your value compare, in case, you submit exist value) with same key[5] `($count + 1)`.
so you can create variable thats indicated your value submit is exist.

```
function findInfo(){
    global $karma_score;
    $counter = count($karma_score);
    $isExist = false;
    foreach ($karma_score as $key => $b) {
        if ($b['NameID'] === $_POST['name']){
            $karma_score[$key]["Karma"] += 5;
            $isExist = true;
        }
    }
    if(!isExist)
        $karma_score[$counter+1] = array("Userid" => $_POST['id'], "NameID" => $_POST['name'], "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => date("Y-m-d"));     
    echo "<br> Here is your updated table.";
    printArray($karma_score);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I gave your function a try, the adding of 5 works but the new user won't create.. Any idea why?

Comment: I found the error, I just had to take the '!' out of the if statement. It works! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Since the first tier of your array has only a numeric index... You'd increment a row like so:

```
$karma_score[0]['Karma'] += 5;
```

...but that's obviously a bit volatile. You may want to use the UserID number for a distinct array key. Then you can easily increment a given user's karma. Like so:

```
$karma_score = array(   
    1 => array("Userid" => 1, "NameID" => 'Doe', "Karma" => 45, "LastLogin" => "2012-08-30"),
    2 => array("Userid" => 2, "NameID" => 'Smith', "Karma" => 123, "LastLogin" => "2012-09-02"),
    3 => array("Userid" => 3, "NameID" => 'Chan', "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => "2011-12-23"),
    4 => array("Userid" => 4, "NameID" => 'Zee', "Karma" => 15, "LastLogin" => "2012-07-01"));
```

If you did that, then you could for example;

```
$karma_score[4]['Karma'] += 5; // Would increment Zee's karma
```

...without looping all over the place trying to find a row that matches the user's ID. But that's getting pretty clunky there. You might consider tossing all of this data into a database at some point. You could also:

```
$karma_score['Zee']['Karma'] += 5;
```

...and really get rid of that unnecessary loop. Creating problems for you, will create more problems for you... A bit of logic clean-up due for the code, bro. :)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response. This is a small project I'm working on to get my hands dirty in PHP. I'll get into databases eventually!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was in:

```
foreach ($karma_score as $key => $b) {
    if ($b['NameID'] === $_POST['name'])
        $karma_score[$key]["Karma"] += 5;
    else 
        $karma_score[$counter+1] = array("Userid" => $_POST['id'], "NameID" => $_POST['name'], "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => date("Y-m-d"));     
}
```

You don't need a foreach, try with my code:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<?php

// Array begin 
$karma_score = array(   array("Userid" => 1, "NameID" => 'Doe', "Karma" => 45, "LastLogin" => "2012-08-30"),
                        array("Userid" => 2, "NameID" => 'Smith', "Karma" => 123, "LastLogin" => "2012-09-02"),
                        array("Userid" => 3, "NameID" => 'Chan', "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => "2011-12-23"),
                        array("Userid" => 4, "NameID" => 'Zee', "Karma" => 15, "LastLogin" => "2012-07-01"));

// Counter for amount of users
$counter = count($karma_score);

// Function to print general array
function printArray($a){
    echo '<table border="1px">';
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach(array_keys($a[0]) as $head){
            echo '<th>'.$head.'</th>';
        }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($a as $b) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['Userid'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['NameID'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['Karma'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$b['LastLogin'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

echo '<br>';

function findInfo()
{
    global $karma_score;
    $counter = count($karma_score);

    //if php>5.5.0 use $names = array_column($karma_score, 'NameID');
    $names = array_map(function($element){return $element['NameID'];}, $karma_score);
    if(in_array($_POST['name'], $names)) {
       $key = array_search($_POST['name'], $names);
       $karma_score[$key]['Karma'] += 5;
    } else {
      $karma_score[$counter] = array("Userid" => $_POST['id'], "NameID" => $_POST['name'], "Karma" => 1, "LastLogin" => date("Y-m-d"));             
    }       

    echo "<br> Here is your updated table.";
    printArray($karma_score);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    findInfo();
}

?>

<br>


Please enter name and id. If name exists, add 5. If not, add user.
<form action="" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID #">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I used your function instead of mine and got this error: Call to undefined function array_column() on line 89. Before I look into it myself maybe you notice something wrong?

Comment: you need php >= 5.5.0